# Why does Eclipse Scala project not find Scala?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I installed the Scala IDE for Eclipse and created a HelloWorld object in the package sample, all using the Eclipse Scala perspective. Now when I click run I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala.Predef$
    at conformal/sample.HelloWorld$.main(HelloWorld.scala:7)
    at conformal/sample.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:769)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1055)
    ... 2 more
```

which I can only assume means that the scala jar file is not available. Which seems super strange. Also according to the Package Explorer it seems to be listed. Must I still add it to the run configuration somehow?

This is what hte PAckage explorer looks like [image]

I have tried two version of Java:

- adoptopenjdk12-openj9
- adoptopenjdk13-openj9

Comment: What is the jdk and scala version that you are using?

Comment: Does deleting the `module-info.java` file fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger No makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there could be couple of reasons for this behavior:

- jdk12 or jdk 13 is incompatible with scala library container 2.12.3. You need to have jdk version downgraded as mentioned in [jdk compatability document](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html#jdk-12-compatibility-notes)
- scala library jar is not added to the classpath. To add scala library to the classpath via Eclipse: Right-click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Buildpath -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Select the Scala Library

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: As for the Classpath it is listed under Modulepath and when I try to add it under ClassPath it complaints about duplicate entry. Regarding versions I think you are on to something but which version should I be running then? The table does not mention Scala version 2.12.3.

Comment: You can use jdk 10,9 or 8 and if you want to use jdk 12 or 13, upgrade the scala jar version.I prefer running in jdk 8.